# Creating a single jar file for multiple jars each with a separate main class

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I want to combine two different jar files(having separate and independent main class) into one single runnable jar.

Suppose, I have two jars, A.jar and B.jar, both with independent main class. Both the class files inside the jars do not depend on each other. Now, I need a single runnable jar so that I could execute both the jars together.

Another thing that I wanted to know... Is it possible to specify two main classes inside the same manifest file?
Is there any way to run two different codes together other than re-writing the code and creating a separate class for each?
Is this possible?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: How would Java know which main class to execute?

Comment: Well, I'll use the manifest file for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have oneach Main. So I would add an interface, IModule, say. Then each class implements them and you discover them through reflection.

Comment: I'll try using interface... Thanks